# Is there way to autofill in excel where every blank row in a column is filled with the value of the closest non-empty cell above the blank row?

Tags: excel, powerquery

A simplified example of what I am looking for is a quick way (either a tool or a keystroke) to fill a table where every 5 rows of the first column has a different operator name. The fill would place the first name into the first 5 rows of the table, the second name into rows 6 - 10, and the third name into rows 11 - 15. The images below are a visual representation of before and after the fill.

I am aware of different ways to fill the rows one operator at a time in this example, but is there a way to fill all three in one go? This would be very helpful in larger scale situations. Thanks!

[Excel table before filling column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtFDA.png)
[Excel table after filling column A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQMPA.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open PowerQuery (Go to `Data` on the ribbon, `Get Data` -> `Launch Power Query Editor ...`) and use Fill Down ...

[image: Fill Down]

**Result**

[image: Result]